# No space between function name and left parenthesis

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

When typing a function in PyCharm, the auto-completion feature inserts a space between function name and left parenthesis like this:

```
myfunction (self):
```

What I would like PyCharm to do is to not insert that space by default, so functions should look like this:

```
myfunction(self):
```

Also I DO want PyCharm to insert the space between certain keywords and the left paranthesis such as:

```
if (), while (), for ()
```

How can I achieve that behaviour?

I have Googled my question for both PyCharm and IntelliJ to no avail.

The reason for the desired formatting is to improve code readability. This works because when client reads the code, they can distinguish function calls from control statements on a subconscious level, before actually thinking about the meaning of the statement.

Comment: Check your codeStyleSettings.xml in the .idea folder in IDEA (If you have it). I think this can be done from there.

Comment: Please note that the parentheses are not part of the `if`, `while`, or `for` syntax.  They're allowable as part of a valid expression, but they aren't a language requirement.  You may well not be able to configure that.

Comment: @GlenPierce no such file exists in my PyCharm project, under Project Files hierarchy.

Comment: @Prune The mentioned character does not affect correctness, but I believe it certainly does affect the code quality(readability).

Comment: Can you click on Settings > Editor >Code Style?

Comment: @Campiador: that's your prerogative as a solo programmer.  However, since the language grammar rules don't require the parentheses, I doubt that you can configure that into the IDE.  Also, please note that your choice is at odds with the PEP-8 coding standards.  Your choice; this is just a heads-up.

Comment: @GlenPierce yes. I open the tab. No idea what to do next.

Comment: @Prune The convention is directly from Linux kernel coding standard, written by Linus Trovalds. https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/40/readings/LinusCodingStyle.txt I explained the science behind it at the end of my question. Also I checked PEP-8, and you are wrong. It is consistent with Linus's rules of indentation. Check for yourself: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation Space after control keywords, no space after function name.

Comment: What I refer to is that you appear to require parentheses on *all* flow control statements.  PEP-8 suggests them for multi-line control expressions, but not for single-line.  That's all I meant.  As I have long learned, UNIX-world standards and Python-world standards are often incompatible in the syntactic sugar and conventions.

Comment: @Prune Interesting. I spent like 10 minutes trying to find that rule. Could you please point me to where in the coding standards that rule is mentioned?

Comment: Sure.  Look under the indentation rules, for the paragraph starting with "When the conditional part of an if -statement is long enough ..."  That spot suggests when to *add* parentheses.  The lack of parentheses is implied by that addition, contrasted with the many examples of one-line if/for/while statements.  As always note that these are not *rules*, they're merely recommendations, despite the number of times I've heard (and used) the phrase "PEP-8 standards".  Remember the [cardinal rule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) :-)

Answer (score 3):

We have this in IDEA:
I'm not sure if this is available in PyCharm. Click Settings > Editor > Code Style

[image]

Comment: That's it. The first three options were checked for me. I unchecked them and now the behavior is just what I wanted. Thanks!